# Should a dropdown list be closed when mouse leaves?

Tags: usability, drop-down-list, hover

Should a dropdown list be automatically closed when you leave current object and navigate to another, or should it remain opened until you open next dropdown list?

---

1. Dropdown closed when mouse leaves

[image: Option 1]

---

2. Dropdown remains opened

[image: Option 2]

Comment: I would say to close when the user goes to another object because that means that the user wants to do another action. If the cursor remains on the same object, I would say to keep it open

Comment: @DimitraMiha: "when the user goes to another object because that means that the user wants to do another action" - or they want the cursor out of the way to read the content of the dropdown.

Comment: Does it close if you click on dropdown of another picture?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Yes it will close if you open another dropdown

Comment: Then +1 to DPS' answer (2nd option).

Comment: I can only say that I usually find it annoying when drop-down lists/menus close when the mouse moves out of the menu.  For one thing, I seldom move the mouse (or in my case, trackball) in a perfectly straight vertical line, so the cursor may wander outside the menu going from A to B, closing the menu and making me start all over again.

Comment: do your user always have a mouse, or do they use other devices? (e.g. fingers on a touch screen. There is no such thing as hovering with fingers.)

Comment: Fast close on mouse-out is one of the most user-hostile ways a dropdown can act. Other people here are being far milder about this than I would be. There are other ways to let a user conveniently close a dropdown.

Comment: Just the other day I had to login on a webpage that has a login form like that... it was impossible to use with KeePass because it kept closing before the it could type the password...

Comment: Close on mouse-out could even be an accessability issue… mice have high point accuracy but low path accuracy, which is why they aren't usually good for drawing. Even after decades of constant use i still accidentally close these things all the time.

Comment: If it doesn't close when you move away the mouse, then how to you get it to close? I'm always annoyed by those popups/dropdowns which stay open and do not have an obvious way to close. Personally, I like it when the thing closes if the mouse is away 0.x seconds...

Comment: @Poly, same as the right-click menu: click anywhere else. I don't think many users will have a problem with this.

Comment: Generally it is annoying if dropdown boxes close too quick, especially if you want to use keyboard or are on mobile touch. However in your example where there are tiles it looks natural (the question is if a drop down is the right control in this case)

Comment: Make it a nested menu, 6 levels deep, like the Windows XP start menu. Try to reliably navigate without accidentally closing it. The experience will provide you with a rather clear answer.

Comment: I don't know if somebody already mention this, but I suggest you to enable the user to close this `dropdown list` also with the 'ESC' button.

Comment: There are a lot of websites that try to do this and fail miserably at it. Things like the small space between where you click to open the dropdown, and the actual dropdown itself, counting as space that would be 'navigating away' from the dropdown, thereby closing it. I find this "feature" generally annoying, unless it is done properly.

Comment: @StarWeaver is correct: Closing on mouse-out is a major accessibility issue. I've come across a number of instances where this kind of thing causes obvious UX issues even for regular users. Now consider the case of an accessibility user who has a mouse but has reduced hand control; a slightly shaky cursor might make your menu virtually impossible to use. If you *must* go with close on mouse-out, then please add a timer over and above the mouse-out to give the user a grace period to move back to the menu. It only has to be an extra half a second to make a massive difference to usability.

Comment: What if the user wants to take a screen shot of the dropdown options by clicking another button elsewhere?

Comment: I can't answer this question because "No." would be too short and the rest would be profanity.

Comment: Btw, the Netflix web site uses hover actions everywhere and it is ***incredibly annoying***, especially with narrow scrollbars on drop lists, one pixel off with your mouse or touchpad and sad trombone, time to start your action over. For double insanity points they also do this over controls whose actual size changes when you hover over them, leaving you chasing things all around the page and having to plot strategic paths with your cursor to maneuver it around things that move what you're going for. Please, I beg of UI designers everywhere, stop using hover actions. ***It improves nothing.***

Answer (score 274, accepted):

**For consistency, the behavior should be based on the calling action; click or hover**.

If you are opening the dropdown on click, let the user toggle and close it, or close the previous dropdown when user clicks on another thumbnail.

If you are opening the dropdown on mouse-over, close it on mouse-out.

Comment: As an addition to this, I would suggest having it fade out allowing recovery before its gone. I can't count the number of times I have slipped off a dropdown multiple times in a row.

Comment: I would suggest caution for fade out depending on what the dropdown covers. I recall being frustrated waiting for dropdowns to disappear so I can get at what they are covering. And if the timing isn't quite synched to the rendering having it pop back up after I believe it is fully faded out, and then having to wait again.

Comment: I'd expect a dropdown that I clicked to open to close when it loses focus

Comment: Simply don't use dropdown-on-hover! Those things are awful! Showing options on hover can work, but you shouldn't be asked to navigate a mouse maze to make them show up!

Comment: And whats about touch devices? They habe no on-hover?

Comment: @FrankL Then you use the on-click (on-touch) behavior.

Comment: One addition to this; if you're going to show/hide on hover, _make sure your detection area is reasonable_, especially for the mouse-out event.  In particular I've encountered some _very poor_ implementations where if you weren't extremely careful in mousing through the caret at the top of the box the entire menu would disappear on you when you went to click on one of the items.  If you don't know how to have a detection area that's larger than the menu itself, don't show/hide menus on hover.

Comment: Instead of fade out, I would recommend a pause, then an immediate disappearance, to mitigate the issue described by @starrise.

Comment: Also, I've encountered plenty of websites where "on-click" was sustituted for "on-touch" and then when you went to move the screen (Because the menu was smaller than the total screen size), the menu disappeared. HATE HATE HATE!

Comment: @aroth exactly. I've seen sites where, perhaps due to a CSS or browser glitch, the menu appears a few pixels away from the button that invoked it -- just trying to move the mouse in a straight line from button to menu would cause the menu to disappear as soon as the mouse attempts to cross that gap!

Comment: I think this is more complicated as the menu button is exposed on hover and activated on click. If the button is not visible I would expect its sub actions to also be not visible. In the second example the menu is activated on hover and deactivated on click which also breaks your rule.

Answer (score 81):

The answer to this question is part of a more general UX rule: moving the mouse (without a button held down) is not input, and applications should not respond to it by taking any nontrivial action. Trivial actions include things like adding/removing underline, changing color, or performing a small, spatially isolated animation to indicate clickability. Showing or hiding information/UI elements is nontrivial, and really annoying to users who move the mouse cursor (which might be oversized for accessibility reasons!) off the top of the text they're trying to read so that they can read it.

**Added** (since the comments seem to be generating debate over what is "trivial"): My intent is that an action/reaction to mouse movement is trivial if:

1. Omitting it entirely would not remove information or limit the ability to interact with the interface, and
2. Presence of the action does not disrupt or interfere with ability to read or interact with the interface.

Mouseover dropdowns/menus (and also tooltips) fail both criteria if they can't also be activated by clicks, and fail the second one either way unless you arrange for them to appear in a special area where they don't obscure other content.

Comment: This isn't *quite* a blanket rule.  Ever heard of mouseover text?

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, and it's **hideous** ux. I disable it wherever I can find a way to. Just as moving the mouse off a UI element doesn't mean you don't want to read what's there, moving it onto an element doesn't necessarily mean you don't want to read adjacent text that the mouseover text pops up in front of.

Comment: Well, I disagree strongly.  It's a way to find out more about an unfamiliar UI without doing something (clicking) that you can expect to trigger some actual action.  However, it *should* have a reasonable delay; most do.  Check the mouseover on SE itself.  And note that when you enter "mouseover mode" there is no delay on switching from item to item.  This is great UX IMO.

Comment: @Wildcard: There are much better ways to achieve the same, non-invasively, like a dedicated feedback area/status bar that shows information about what's under the mouse pointer. That's basically the way browsers have always presented link destinations.

Comment: @Wildcard: Delay makes it even worse, because the mouseover text inevitably appears after you've moved your hand off the mouse, then you have to put your hand back on the mouse to move it until you find a place where mouseover text won't reappear, **and** wait a second or two to make sure you were right that no new mouseover text will appear.

Comment: Survey more newbie users.  I work with such a lot, and I think you'll find that they hover over a button wondering if it's the right one, and look *at the cursor,* so mouseover text informs them right where they need it.  And that most of them have never noticed the link preview area in the browser, or don't know what it is.  Newbie users don't necessarily *see* every section of the screen the way advanced users do.  They only see the narrow part they're looking at.  Toolbars seem to be a bewildering array of random icons.

Comment: @Wildcard: Then get rid of the bewildering array of random icons. Don't use "this feature compensates for the badness of some other ui design with newbie users" as an excuse for bad ux.

Comment: Well, I can't argue with that.  I'm not a UX designer, though—I train users.  So I'll take what I can get.  :)  You make very good points, thanks.

Comment: @Wildcard: Actually, I would classify tooltips (which always have a delay before they show) as trivial actions. They are hints, and nothing more, and if you rely on them for anything more than a non-trivial reason, then you're doing something wrong. (I would also say they're great UX, because they're the ultimate in contextual help: they show up exactly when users need help, but stay out of the way otherwise.)

Comment: @FighterJet: They're nontrivial because they obscure adjacent content you might be trying to read. And they don't "stay out of the way otherwise" unless you're constantly careful to keep your pointer off of anything that might have a tooltip when you put down the mouse.

Comment: @FighterJet, the way I've always seen it, you should be able to click any menu item and be taken to a page which will display the menu item's sub-categories. Sometimes you want the parent menu item of a dropdown to actually be a link as well. In this context, being shown the dropdown menu could be considered trivial, as you are merely revealing a shortcut to what lies beyond by actually clicking the parent link.

Comment: Among other things, you might mouse-away because your mouse pointer is *in the other application you're trying to copy the data to*.  Also mobile.

Comment: @FighterJet - You may classify tooltips that way (and I might agree with that classification), however according to how this answer is written that classification is incorrect.  Tooltips will often obscure text and other components on the page, and thus fail the "does not disrupt or interfere with ability to read or interact with the interface" test suggested in the answer.  Which means (according to the answer) that tooltips should only be activated by click.  Which I think is awful UX, and a good example of why this answer _is just plain wrong_.

Comment: @aroth: There are ways to reconcile tooltips with the principles in this answer, like leaving a small region below the toolbar empty and always centering the tooltip immediately under the toolbar button rather than on the mouse pointer. But I still maintain that the need for tooltips is indicative of deeper UX bugs: the "bewildering array of random icons" as Wildcard put it. They're a workaround users have come to accept for bad UX, rather than a good in their own right.

Comment: @R.., does Stack Exchange's editor have a bad UX? I'd say it's pretty good. It's hard to avoid little buttons in this case without adding a lot of clutter, and the icons are pretty indicative of their actions. But if the icon isn't enough, hovering over the button will provide a short 1-2 word tooltip as a reminder. Once the user had learned the icon (even if they learned it in MS Word in 2001), the textual help is unnecessary. __In practice__, tooltips do not get in the way. Furthermore, they are expected by users and always work consistently, something that cannot be said about hover menus.

Comment: @FighterJet: If you insist on having them, find a way to make sure they don't cover content. Most of them do. Several I noticed doing it in the past 30 minutes: browser tabs' tooltips/mouseover text covering current url, gmail sender info popups covering half my inbox.

Answer (score 43):

I honestly think that hover menus are bad UX entirely.

I suspect the only reason they exist in the first place is that they are easier to implement in pure CSS, so the developer can get away with something the user doesn’t necessarily want.

Here are some points to consider:

- Most operating systems wait for a user click before activating a menu. The hover menu goes against a well established pattern.
- The operating system has menus in a separate part of the window, where their behavior is anticipated. Hover menus are part of the content, and compete with the rest of the content.
- Users routinely use a mouse without any intent, or simply to follow their eyes. The hover menu disrupts this behavior, often obscuring content which the user was looking at.
- Touch devices, at this point in time, do not include a true hover action. Hover menus represent a different behavior between desktop and touch devices. In fact, they often behave as click menus in this context.
- Non-sighted users will not experience the hover menu at all, which is a small mercy.

While a web application is not exactly the same as a desktop application, there are conventions and prior experiences, as well as expectations, to accommodate.

Click (or touch) activated menus are, these days, easy enough to implement with a few lines of CSS and (non-jQuery) JavaScript.

The short answer is a dropdown should be activated deliberately and deactivated deliberately. This is not with mouse move, but with a click or a touch.

Comment: You can actually do clickable dropdowns entirely in CSS and HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/pq0mxvj2/.

Comment: @Yay295 The problem is that `:checked` doesn’t work with Certain Legacy Browsers™. You can also use `:active` but that doesn’t work well on touch devices.

Comment: `:active` elements are only active while you are clicking them; it doesn't work well on any device. Chrome and Firefox have supported `:checked` since version 1, and IE since 9, meaning less than 0.5% of people browsing the web are unsupported.

Comment: @Yay295 not that that doesn't mean 0.5% of your users would be unsupported.

Comment: Your list need one more point: "It's super, super annoying when the drop down disappears and have you have to align and move your mouse *juuuuuust* right to actually click anything in the drop down/pop up."

Comment: @Yay295 I mentioned the use of `:active`, but that was a mistake. I have made it work with a combination of `:focus` and `tabindex="0"`. That way I impose a minimal change to HTML, and the item appropriately loses focus when you click anywhere else, just like the real thing. Unfortunately, that doesn’t work on touch devices.

Answer (score 23):

I agree with DPS's answer, however I'd opt for explicit behaviour - thus clicking to open and clicking (or pressing Esc) to close.

### Why not "on-hover"?

If the user opens the dropdown and makes a more generous mouse move (move away the cursor to read all the options) - the menu disappears increasing the annoyance.

There is something else I'd like to mention - when the dropdown appears, it is placed bottom-left to the mouse cursor. In my opinion it should be placed bottom-right. The user follows the mouse pointer and in majority of cultures we tend to process the information from left to right. If the user is focused on the mouse pointer, they expect the menu to appear to the right, so their data processing flow is not disturbed.

Having the above in mind - if you go for "on hover" option, it is very easy to move the cursor away from the dropdown and by this close it.

Comment: I would have the dropdown appear to the right, just so it doesn't completely cover the object it's applying to.

Comment: Or move the menu icon to the left so the dropdown still covers the object it applies to.

Comment: The other benefit to explicit behavior is, of course, that it works on touch-only devices (think phones and tablets). We do not know enough about the OP's scenario to know if that matters, but I like to keep it in mind whenever possible.

Comment: Good point about placement, +1.  On both Mac and Windows context menus (for right clicking) appear bottom-right to the mouse cursor, unless you are right up close against the right hand side of the monitor—in which case Mac puts dropdown bottom-left from the mouse cursor, and Windows puts dropdown bottom-right as far as they can so it ends up flush against the right side of your screen, with the cursor near the center of its top.  (I think the Mac behavior is cleaner, personally.)

Comment: @Wildcard: the Mac behaviour when cursor is near the right-hand edge of the screen is application-dependent.  E.g. (at least in OS X 10.9, on the computer I’m using now) the Finder gives what you describe as the Mac behaviour, while Safari gives what you describe as the Windows behaviour.

Comment: @PLL, interesting; on 10.11.6 it's the same in Finder, Safari, Adobe Reader, LibreOffice....

Answer (score 12):

...Or you can consider changing the design altogether. Personally I think it's not a good idea to hide functionality under three dots.

## Show actions on hover

You can remove click/hover altogether by showing actions straight on hover. I'd argue it's better since you save the click (I'm not showing move/rename for brevity).

[image]

## Show actions in the main screen

If design allows, actions can always be visible on the main screen. If you think that icons are vague, you can add tooltip or change layout to show icons with labels.

[image]

Comment: For simplicity, you can allow renaming by clicking on the title.

Comment: Underrated answer of the day!

Answer (score 11):

You might consider adding a way for the user to close the drop down. This way there is no confusion on how to close it and no annoyance of accidentally closing it by moving the mouse out of the area.

[image: Windows style drop down with close button.]

Comment: Nice, simple and usable.  No gratuitous code.  Don't forget that the average user doesn't care about how clever things are, they just want them to work.

Comment: I would agree with this if it didn't look so bad.  Not trying to knock on your design at all because it's not your fault; the `x` just looks so out-of-place in this menu for some reason.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann it only looks out of place because of the colour its been given in the example. But I guess that was to highlight it as an addition rather than to suggest actually making it that colour. Make it a more subtle grey and it would look fine.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the close button to mesh a little better with the given example.

Comment: This looks a bit like a delete option of the first item in the list.

Comment: It really does! Should probably make the drop down more window like in it's appearance. Putting the close button on a bar or something.

Answer (score 9):

I happen to find that behavior **quite annoying**, especially with nested menus, on YouTube on a HTPC.  The remote mouse is easy to get off track and *wham* I have to start over.  Anyone with less than perfect dexterity will find this to be annoying.

Please don't make the *precise path* of the pointer a necessary part of the UI.  Some people have mobility issues, some have less than idea pointing devices, some are in a moving vehicle, etc.

Comment: +1 for the mobility issues. Don't expect all users to be able to produce perfect pointer movements

Answer (score 6):

Apart from what DPS answered, which talks about consistency, I would suggest you go with the *click* instead of *hover*. It seems like you have a grid layout, and am sure you don't want to annoy your users popping up the action menu when they move the mouse over these grid items.

It is better to keep it explicit, only when the user tries to click on the action button. One more thing you can do here is that change the icon so that it is clear that he needs to click back to toggle it, something like:

[image]

Make sure that it should collapse if user clicks elsewhere on the page (this also includes the users who try to click on the action menu of another image)

---

Another thing you can try out is to have common action buttons and let the user select the images on long click. The only thing which might be an issue over here is the move option. I'm not sure what functionality you have in place there(i.e is it draggable, click sort and so on)

You can smoothly animate these icons once the user selects >= 1 image in the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd say: click on `...` to open, click on anywhere but the dropdown menu to close. Once we click the open button, we tend to move away and going back and pressing it again can be exhausting. There's also a danger of pressing the first item on the dropdown list. I've seen the open/close on hover performing so badly that I think shouldn't be an option. What happens is that the dropdown disappears once you start moving from the `...` button towards the menu.

Answer (score 3):

- Mouse-over,mouse-leave events to open-close a drop-down menu is in general
  not a good idea.
- Preferably click or touch events should open-close
  a drop-down menu.

To be more specific... 
In the example you provided in your question where the drop-down opens above an image element one thing you could do is lower the opacity of the menu (e.g. to 20%) if the user moves the mouse out of the menu-box. In that case you will have in your hands a partially transparent menu so that the user could still view the element below the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately closing such a list even if the mouse is a pixel out of its region for a split second - especially with dropdowns where the region changes due to submenus (which also means your user has to repeat a whole navigation chain in the worst case) etc. - tends to be very susceptible to spurious mouse movements (aggravated if: bad mouse skills, a mouse set up for speed not precision, a vibration-rich work environment, small size of UI elements).

Letting the opened menu stay forever can end up in a user being confused about how to close a menu that is covering content or other UI elements.

Delays and some hysteresis between activation and deactivation regions will probably follow the principle of least astonishment best...

Answer (score 1):

### Mobile or not?

Some years ago, when the only input was using the mouse (or pressing the Alt key... nobody really expected that) a mouse hover was a good option.

But not anymore.

The minimized design you are using implies that the design is intended for a small device, so there is no real mouse hover.

My opinion is click to open and click to close.

### A timer?

But you also **could include a timer**. If no input is made in some seconds, that menu could collapse.

### Some problems with the mouse out

- Evident problem with a mobile device.
- A desktop user could have issues, for example with a defective mouse that moves the mouse pointer like crazy (I had some cheap mouses sometimes)
- Some laptop pads can be tricky to use. A mouse hover/out needs more skill from the user.
- One additional problem thinking on a mouse hover - mouse out approach is that the user could need to move the pointer for some reason, but still needed that menu open. A screen capture? Working in another window?

Comment: I disagree on the timer idea. "If no input is made in some seconds, that menu could collapse". This will inevitably lead to (1) the menu closing before some users could read all the options, (2) the menu closing right as the users was about to click an option and instead the user clicks the item (3) there's no clear reason on why the menu is closing.

Answer (score -2):

## Once mouse leaves, everything goes away

This is simple logic, and working with prototypes would show it immediately. Using your same caffe images, we can do a simple analogy. Let's say you go to *caffe1*, then open the menu and order something. You leave and go to *caffe2*. Where at it.... would you expect to see *caffe1* menu or *caffe2* menu? What would you think if you see *caffe1's* menu instead of *caffe2's*?

Well, as tou can see the answers are obvious, and they're based in layout construction principles. They not only apply to your example, but they apply to everything. Think of a terrain (layout) where you build a house with different rooms. Some might be similar, but they all will have special characteristics and possibilities: you'll have a kitchen, a bathroom, a dining room, a laundry, etc. All of them with different possibilities. You'll be able to cook in the kitchen, but you won't be able to do it in the laundry.

This is known as **plane and dimensions building**, where you have different planes and different dimensions which are related to physics and how we perceive the world around us (hence, while it only applies to your specific case in a tangential way, it includes *time* dimensions)

**Material Design** uses this metaphor of sheets of material with dimensions and depths (although contrary to popular belief, they didn't invent it). And it's really easy to implement: simply start with a blank sheet of paper. Then add elements as needed. Use post-it or cut from other pieces of paper. You'll create prototypes where you'll be able to see how each element connects, and more important, **how they doesn't connect.**

## Hover vs Click

If this is responsive, go with click, bar none. There's no hover behavior on mobile, so building hover based behaviors is a waste of time. However, if this is adaptive, you can have a hover behavior for desktop (better for discovering) and click behavior for mobile. However, click to open and click to close is not needed, it's more effort and friction with no gain at all. Just do this:

- **Desktop** (adaptive): `on mouse leave`, close menu.
- **Mobile** (responsive): `on click (menu2)`, close menu 1

This way you save a click and avoid to have unnoticed menus open when you're in a completely different property

Comment: The problem with your analogy is that moving the mouse does not signal intent to perform an action like walking between rooms does, and that while using the mouse, it has a precise point, but an imprecise path. So if you accidentally wander out of the menu a pixel or two while going to click a menu item, then bam, it's gone.

Comment: There is unfortunately no mouse in all cases nowadays

Comment: @FighterJet, if you're over an object, you're over an object. If you're not, you're not. That's precisely the idea of on_hover. If you move away, you're doing an explicit action to move out. Otherwise we'd be in an scenario where every hover behavior should be permanent "just in case". All this being said, do a Google search for *mouse hover intent* and you'll find how to solve even this "problem" you mention (keep in mind I didn't go deep into implementation since this is not an implementation forum)

Comment: @eckes, hence why I mentioned different scenarios for desktop and mobile (which obviously don't use a mouse)

Comment: Thank you for the downvotes on a clearly correct question. Would love to know the reasoning, but guess there's none

Comment: One of the things you need to consider is people with physical limitations like shaking hands, that need to place the pointer (through involuntary and/or imprecise movements) and then can press a button. If the menu goes away due to those involuntary movements, the menu is unusable for those users. Even 'regular' users can move the mouse when they sneeze, or if there's dirt in the mouse's ball or optics.